# What is KeyboardEvent#detail?

Tags: javascript

I have not found any information what the property 'detail' in KeyboardEvent is used for in JavaScript.

See [this example](http://jsbin.com/fuwujuremi/1/edit?html,output) and press for example the key , (comma). Detail property does have value 0 (tested in Chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `detail` property is not actually specific to `KeyboardEvent` objects, but is inherited from `UIEvent`. See the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) for what this means for a specific event type.

> The `UIEvent.detail` read-only property, when non-zero, provides the current (or next, depending on the event) click count.